# Resolution for Waveshare SpotPear 3.2 inch LCD with RaspberryPI 1 Model B?

Tags: raspbian

I managed to install my 3.2 screen on a pi running Raspbian. Everything works fine...the only thing that bothers me is that i cant really use the raspbian's gui enviroment (startx). Only the console fits nice with the current resolution, everything else is really hard to work with.
There is no way to scroll down the screen.

Is there a way i can increase the resolution at all so everything turns small ?
Of course i tried to do that from the monitor settings but all i got was 320x240 and auto.
-Thanks

Comment: I know this is not a real answer, but I think [LXDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE), the default DE (desktop environment) used on Raspbian, has zoom -- Ctrl +, Ctrl -, if that helps a bit.   The monitor resolution is limited by the hardware, and probably this screen only has one (320x240), so what you really want to do is configure the desktop widgets to be bigger.  You could ask about that on [LXDE's forum](http://forum.lxde.org/) and if you find a solution, come back and post your own answer.   An issue may be sorting out two different configs, one for the spotpear and one for normal.

Comment: Ctrl +/- didnt work :/ I give the forums a try.
Thanks